# How can I change the user path for .NET?

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

After changing my username and user path (e.g. /Users/) in OSX settings, when I try to use the `dotnet` command to install a package like `dotnet new --install CelesteMod.Templates` I get the following error:

```
[2023-01-18 16:09:16.528] [Debug] [Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Installers.NuGet.NuGetInstaller] => [Execute]: Uninstalling CelesteMod.Templates::1.0.2 failed. Details:System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/Users/<old username>/.templateengine/packages/CelesteMod.Templates.1.0.2.nupkg'.
   at System.IO.FileSystem.DeleteFile(String fullPath)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Installers.NuGet.NuGetInstaller.UninstallAsync(IManagedTemplatePackage templatePackage, IManagedTemplatePackageProvider provider, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Failed to install CelesteMod.Templates::1.0.2, the template package is invalid.
```

Comment: You probably need to clear your NuGet cache and then do the install. Looks like old path is cached.

Comment: @Kit I tried that using `dotnet nuget locals all --clear` but it still throws the same error.

Comment: I doubt this, but try it too... clear the HTTP NuGet cache: `~/.local/share/NuGet/v3-cache`. Also maybe search for your old user name and see if it shows up somewhere.

Comment: Have you checked all your environment variables, to see if there are any (perhaps with a name similar to USERNAME or USER) that still has your old username?

Comment: @zivkan Yeah, both of those env vars contain my new username.

Comment: @zivkan @Kit I think I found the issue within the cache used for the dotnet template engine located at `~/.templateengine/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue lies within the [.NET/NuGet template engine](https://github.com/dotnet/templating) cache since it doesn't automatically update for some reason. I just deleted the `~/.templateengine/` folder recursively and re-downloaded all my templates using `dotnet new` from the CLI.